# Elastic Sink Connector not working new version

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I have used the "io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector" version 13.0.0.

I am doing the SMT for this connector. but I got the below error.

**Found a topic name 'es.contact3.model' that doesn't match the assigned partitions. The connector doesn't support topic mutating SMTs**

I got the error even though I set the "flush.syncronously": "true".

My config is as follows,

```
{
    "type.name": "_doc",
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector",
    "topics": "es.contact.model",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "transforms": "Dealership",
    "key.ignore": "true",
    "input.data.format": "AVRO",
    "transforms.Dealership.type": "io.confluent.connect.transforms.ExtractTopic$Value",
    "transforms.Dealership.field": "indexTopicName",
    "schema.ignore": "true",
    "name": "ContactElasticSinkConnector",
    "flush.syncronously": "true",
    "connection.url": "http://192.168.1.7:19200",
    "transforms.Dealership.skip.missing.or.null": "true"
}
```

Comment: Error is self descriptive - The connector doesn't support topic mutating SMTs. Flush settings don't matter. Remove the transform

Comment: From the article(https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/current/overview.html), These SMT limitations are inapplicable to the Elasticsearch Sink connector when the flush.syncronously configuration property is set to true.

Comment: The documentation could be wrong, and its a bug. I'm just reading what the error says

Comment: Will this feature (SMT) come again in a future release?

Comment: I don't work for Confluent; I cannot answer that. You can create a support ticket if you think you have found a bug.  My experience with Elasticsearch is to create the index mappings ahead of time for the necessary names. It's not that the SMT will not work - it is that the automatic index mapping will be unable to create the index on its own

Answer (score 2):

I faced this same issue and decided to try what you did within your question. There is a typo within:

```
"flush.syncronously": "true"
```

It should be:

```
"flush.synchronously": "true"
```

Simply making this correction worked for me.